# Sonar does not see default case when using switch(String)

Tags: switch-statement, sonarqube

using jdk 1.7 (so i can use String switches and the multicatch)

when running my code through  sonar i got the following message:

```
switch (extension) {
```

Switch statement found where default case is missing

i understand what its saying but it is not right see my code below:
Why am i getting this error.

```
private void handlefileformats(String location) {
    try {
        String extension = location.substring(location.length() - 4);
        switch (extension) {
        case ".xml":
                      logger.info(LoggerMessages.getLoadxml());
                      break;
        case ".txt":
        case ".csv":
                      logger.info(LoggerMessages.getLoadcsv());
                      break;
        default:
            throw new IncorrectFileException(location, sets);
        }
    } catch (IOException || IncorrectFileExceptione) {
        logger.fatal(LoggerMessages.getException(), e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

p.s. the code above is a simplified version of the original thats why i do not use the else if.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed Java7 will be supported in Sonar 2.12.

Comment: hmm ok thanks that explains a lot, should have searched for a compatibility problem myself.